# How to mark selected columns of a table for display

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I use PostgreSQL 10.1 and:

```
CREATE TABLE human
(
    id        ... NOT NULL,
    gender    ...,
    height    ...,
    weight    ...,
    eye       ...,
    hair      ...,
    ...
);
```

I have an input form through which I insert the data. I wish an elegant and proper way by which I can **SELECT** which columns required to be **DISPLAYED** in that form, something like `weight ... DISPLAYED,` or `eye ... NOT DISPLAYED,` .

- One way is to correspond **NULL** with **DISPLAYED** (when NOT NULL then display it, or when NULL then do not display it) and use `information_schema` which (corresponding) makes me no so happy:
- Another way is to:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE human_column
  (
      id                ... NOT NULL,
      characteristic    character varying(...),
      is_displayed      boolean
  );
  ```

  where `characteristic` data are the names of the columns of `human` table.

Is there a better way to add a direct foreign attribute to the columns of a table? (In `51.7. pg_attribute` there is a column named `attoptions`. Would it be used?)

Comment: you should not update `pg_attribute` for sure. and you can add custom "attributes" to a column - so just have list saved somewhere. but you will need to dynamiccaly create a view or alike then to return a a wanted list. other wise if the list is not modifiable - just create a view?..

Comment: you could make up your own 'language" and use the per-column COMMENT for annotations. Kinda brittle, though

Comment: I'm thinking that this is not related to persistence layer(database) of your application. Rather it is highly related to your server.

Comment: I apologize, I erased by mistake an answer!

Comment: @VaoTsun: I agree, a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html) seems like the most elegant, reliable solution.

Comment: You could use a (single) json or hstore column that stores a map with additional attributes

Comment: Can you use Dynamic SQL in your project?

Answer (score 0):

specifying "options" for columns to define if they will be "displayed" or not seems a little overhead. Imagine you keep such list in `human_column`. To modify it you would need to update it with new `is_displayed` values. Then you would need to build column list to be selected in query.

When you create a view, you do the same (specify a list of columns to be displayed) and then you can just query the view, without need to dynamically build the query. Also you can always check the current list of included columns from catalog or information_schema.

The only "not cosy" feature of a view - you can't change columns in it, thus you have to drop and create it again.

drop/create view on demand looks cheaper to me then dynamically building query with list of columns on each select still.

demo:

```
db=# create view v as select oid,datname from pg_database;
CREATE VIEW
db=# select * from v;
  oid  |  datname
-------+-----------
 13505 | postgres
 16384 | t
     1 | template1
 13504 | template0
 16419 | o
(5 rows)
```

checking list of columns:

```
db=# select column_name,ordinal_position,column_default,is_nullable,data_type,character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'v';
 column_name | ordinal_position | column_default | is_nullable | data_type | character_maximum_length
-------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------
 oid         |                1 |                | YES         | oid       |
 datname     |                2 |                | YES         | name      |
(2 rows)
```

same for original table:

```
db=# select column_name,ordinal_position,column_default,is_nullable,data_type,character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'pg_database';
  column_name  | ordinal_position | column_default | is_nullable | data_type | character_maximum_length
---------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------
 datname       |                1 |                | NO          | name      |
 datdba        |                2 |                | NO          | oid       |
 encoding      |                3 |                | NO          | integer   |
 datcollate    |                4 |                | NO          | name      |
 datctype      |                5 |                | NO          | name      |
 datistemplate |                6 |                | NO          | boolean   |
 datallowconn  |                7 |                | NO          | boolean   |
 datconnlimit  |                8 |                | NO          | integer   |
 datlastsysoid |                9 |                | NO          | oid       |
 datfrozenxid  |               10 |                | NO          | xid       |
 datminmxid    |               11 |                | NO          | xid       |
 dattablespace |               12 |                | NO          | oid       |
 datacl        |               13 |                | YES         | ARRAY     |
(13 rows)
```